# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error while loading laravel css file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

While executing a web page after loading HTML, CSS file is not loading & not applying the UI changes.

In browser console it is showing the following error **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED**

One more issue is "that error is occuring only for the first time", If I reload the page the error will be gone & will load the CSS properly.

*One solution I found after browsing is to enable gzip encoded, That is already in place.*

[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhwxY.png)

Comment: check whether it is showing in chrome only or in all browsers

Comment: Route::get('/') pointing to the correct controller/code?
also what comes up when you click the console error? whats it show in the file?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of an annoying error. But I'll do my best Lacking what information I have on your error exactly.

> What is this error?

**This can happen when an HTTP request's headers say that the content is gzip encoded, but it isn't. It doesn't always happen, as you've discovered. But happens occasionally.**

> What can you do?

1. Check to see if  Route::get('/') pointing to the correct
   controller/code?
2. check to see if `output_compression` is added to your `php.ini`
   **Add this code: `zlib.output_compression = On`**
3. try going to `/config/config.php`(this may not be right in your case) and set the following to false `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;`

> Further reading

(more about what the error actually is)

https://superuser.com/questions/172951/chrome-error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed

https://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/runtime-errors/google-inc/google-chrome/330-chrome-error-330/

Comment: I tried all the possibilities but still, the error occurs. I haven't tried `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;` because it will slow down the application.

Answer (score 2):

As I referred about this cause of error, I think adding `zlib.output_compression = On` to `php.ini` will help you.

You can find this `php.ini` file in your php installed folder. In that find `zlib.output_compression` and initially it will be in `OFF` stage. Change it to `zlib.output_compression = On`.

For more information you can refer https://stefantsov.com/fixing-err_content_decoding_failed-in-apachephp/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Cloudflare make sure Brotli is enabled.

To enable Brotli, follow these steps.

1. Log in to your Cloudflare account.
2. Choose the appropriate domain.
3. Click the Speed app.
4. Click the Optimization tab.
5. Toggle the Brotli switch to On.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168396-What-will-Cloudflare-compress-

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was this:

```
throw new CHttpException(Yii::t('general', 'This category has no product.'));
```

Becose I use Framework Yii 1.1, I changed that with this:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('notification', "This category has no product.");
```

And in front-end I display the message like this:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('notification')) {
    echo '<div>' . Yii::app()->user->getFlash('notification') . "</div>\n";
   }
```